# var a:Number = 5 vs var a=5 (ActionScript)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Last night I thought about this question in Flash

```
var a:Number = 5;
var a = 5;
```

What declaration is better? Does first declaration work faster and take less memory?
All examples of AS contain first declaration method(e.g. http://actionscriptexamples.com/2010/05/03/getting-started-with-the-tlftextfield-class-in-actionscript-3-0-and-flash-cs5/).

```
var tlfTxt:TLFTextField = new TLFTextField();
```

Why do they use first method instead of second?

Answer (score 7):

Also think about optimization. Even though you can declare your variable with no type, like

`var a:* = 5`, what can be used awesomely, still consider the following optimization test:

```
var a = 5;
var b:* = 5;
var c:Number = 5;
var d:int = 5;
var e:uint = 5;

var time_start:Number = getTimer();

for(var i:int = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    a += 1;
    //b += 1;
    //c += 1;
    //d += 1;
    //e += 1;
}

var time_stop:Number = getTimer();

trace(time_stop - time_start, "ms");

//a.) 650 ms
//b.) 651 ms
//c.) 106 ms
//d.) 69 ms
//e.) 69 ms
```

The results show each round on an average machine. Whatever the numbers are exactly in the example above, the point is to see the rate:

In cases *a* and *b*, we didn't give a type to the variable. In the third case (*c.*) we gave it a type, and we reached a **6.14** times speed increase.

In cases *d* and *e*, you can see what happens if you really set the type specifically: integer and unsigned integers. This case, so if you use integers, the speed you can gain is really big (**10x**).

Think about this when writing random functions, big calculations or complex engines.

Answer (score 2):

Always define a type. As mentioned, if you don't the compiler will choose for you, and it may not be as expected.

It also becomes important when dealing with classes. For example you create a private variable `foo` in your class, such as:

```
private var _foo; // no type is defined
```

Later down the track, you want to add a get/set property for it:

```
public function get foo():??? { return _foo; }
public function set foo(val:???):void { _foo = val; }
```

What would you be passing in? And how do you document this for someone else to use?

Where as if you had

```
private var _foo:Number;

public function get foo():Number { return _foo; }
public function set foo(val:Number):void { _foo = val; }
```

It is clear, straight away what foo does in both the get/set cases.

And one more thing. If you want to create a MovieClip variable which references something on the stage, say:

```
var mymc = stage_mc; // Hmmm, not so good
```

If you wanted to call a MovieClip method on mymc, say play(), the compiler will throw an error because it doesn't 'know' mymc has a play method (how would it?). So by typing it (in the sense of adding a type to it, like MovieClip), you are letting the compiler know what methods and properties should be available.

Example:

```
var mymc:MovieClip = stage_mc; // Ahh, much better!
```

It also alows the compiler to do type checking. So in the above example, if you tried to pass in a textfield to the movieclip variable mymc, an error will throw an error. This stops bigger bugs sneaking in.

I'm very passionate about type checking in AS3 - I'm glad Flash finally introduced it, and now that it's here, let's use it!

Comment: Using your method, I repeat the same thing twice, aren't I? (var mymc:MovieClip = stage_mc). There is a similar innovation in C#. There are "var" implicity declaration (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx). Now I can write var a = new MyType(); instead of MyType a = new MyType(); And many peoples recommend us to use "var" strategy instead of "usual" strategy. " var mymc = stage_mc;" - flash doesn't throw exception, however it doesn't display intellisense, but it is IDE's problem. Thus I can see one positive moment in your choice: intellisense. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

In AS3 there is nearly no good reason to not explicitly type something.  There are cases when it is appropriate, but the type system is there to prevent problems.

As for speed / memory differences, this is a pretty good explanation: http://onflex.org/ACDS/AS3TuningInsideAVM2JIT.pdf

Answer (score 0):

in the 2nd statement the compiler has to decide which type he has to use. 
i.e 5 is an integer he also could assume you mean

```
var a:int = 5;  or  var a:uint = 5;
```

also for code completion purposes it's better do define a type ;-) but that's not a real reason to do, because some IDE's can handle these too.

Answer (score 0):

In a language with strong static typing like AS3 you should always be typing your objects at decleration, it will make your code cleaner and help you track down bugs easier.

That said, AS3 is usually quite forgiving and is able to figure out which type you need at runtime. For example, this snippet works fine:

```
    private var foo;

    public final function run():void {

        bar();
        baz();
    }

    private function bar():void {

        foo = 4;
        foo -= 0.5;
        trace( foo ); // traces "3.5"
    }

    private function baz():void {

        foo = "qux";
        trace( foo ); // traces "qux"
    }
```